# will getcwd() and exec('pwd') always match?

Tags: php, bash

**The Question**

Are `getcwd()` and `exec('pwd')` always going to return the same results? And if not under what circumstances would they not?

**What I Tried**

I tried to do `exec('cd ..')` and then `echo exec('pwd')` but that returned the same path that it would have if I didn't do the `cd ..`. Which doesn't surprise me since the `cd ..` probably only lives for the duration of the `exec()` in which it was done.

Comment: They should return the same thing (the latter doing more work); what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Remember that `exec('cd ..')` will run the `cd` command inside a shell spawned by PHP.  Once that shell exits, its local environment is lost.  If you want to change working directories within PHP, use [`chdir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chdir.php) instead.

Comment: @Jack - I want to run a command via the command line but the command requires absolute paths so I'm wanting to resolve the relative path's my program can take in to absolute path's.

Answer (score 3):

A symbolic link being the "working directory" is at least one case where `getcwd()` and `exec('pwd')` can differ - even the bash builtin `pwd` and `/bin/pwd` differ here.

```
# ll /res4/Linux/eldk
lrwxrwxrwx 1 armali ARNGO_res4 9 Oct 20  2008 /res4/Linux/eldk -> eldk3.1.1
# cd /res4/Linux/eldk
# php
<?php
echo getcwd(), "\n";
echo exec('pwd'), "\n";
?>
/res4/Linux/eldk3.1.1
/res4/Linux/eldk
# pwd
/res4/Linux/eldk
# /bin/pwd   
/res4/Linux/eldk3.1.1
```

There are `pwd` options regarding that:

```
   -L, --logical
          use PWD from environment, even if it contains symlinks

   -P, --physical
          avoid all symlinks
```

Apparently, the bash builtin `pwd` defaults to -L, and `/bin/pwd` to -P.

But for most use cases, including yours, both forms would work, so the difference doesn't matter here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to turn relative paths into absolute paths you could use `realpath()`:

```
$abs_path = realpath('../path/to/binary');
```

Comment: The reason I asked the question is because I'm using the absolute path's on the CLI - not in PHP. If doing stat('.') in PHP and stat . in Linux's CLI yield different results...  I'd like to know that. Hence the question.

Comment: @neubert I'm afraid I don't understand the question then. Could you share some code to elaborate?